# Reading shell script result in python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have shell script, which ouput some text result on terminal on execution.

I was able to execute that shellscipt from python script, but I could not store shell script result into python

My python script:

```
import subprocess
#result = subprocess.call(['/root/Desktop/karim/software/cherrypicker1.01/cherryP.sh'],shell = True)   This yields result 0
subprocess.call(['/root/Desktop/karim/software/cherrypicker1.01/cherryP.sh'],shell = True)
print "REsult is  : "
print result
```

cherryP.sh

```
./cherrypicker.sh input.txt
#for line in $(cat input.txt.responses); do echo "$line" ; done
DONE=false
until $DONE
do
  read line || DONE=true
  echo $line   # this will echo the result which I want to use in python script
done < input.txt.responses
```

What wrong I am doing, or what is other plausible solution?

UPDATED cherryP.py

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['/root/Desktop/karim/software/cherrypicker1.01/cherryP.sh'], shell = True)
print result
```

Comment: If you want to read the last line of a file in bash, you can use `tail -n 1 input.txt.responses`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `subprocess.call()`.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['/root/Desktop/karim/software/cherrypicker1.01/cherryP.sh'])
print result
```

Comment: it gives `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error` error

Comment: @user123 : either (preferred) add the line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the top of cherryP.sh, or add `shell=True` to `check_output()`. The latter is a potential security risk, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: tried it, once I execute `python cherryP.y`  execution stops, nothing occurs

Comment: @user123 : It doesn't print `result`? Does cherryP.sh have a long execution time? Have you checked to see if it has terminated? what if you run cherryP.sh directly on the command line?

Comment: yeah now it gives result. ACtually it does not print the "print message" I kept, while in case if using subprocess.call() it was printing

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the result of the external program in a variable, you need to use the `subprocess.check_output` function:

```
subprocess.check_output(['/root/Desktop/karim/software/cherrypicker1.01/cherryP.sh'])
```

The `subprocess.call` function that you are using returns the exit code of the script it executes. Exit code `0`, means that the program finished execution without errors.

You can read more on exit statuses here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: it gives OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error error

Comment: I added the udpated code, can you please suggest conflicts?

Comment: The code that you have executes fine in my environment, and prints the contents of the text file. What are the contents of the file that you are trying to read?

Comment: so your second problem was that the text file is empty?

Comment: actually execution takes time to give final result, I have print few message in between(in batch file which subsequent executes few .jar files) getting the final result. In case of using `check_output` it directly gives final result